# How does drupal recognize the external js library imageflow with the libraries module?

Tags: 8, javascript

I want to upgrade the [imageflow module](https://www.drupal.org/project/imageflow) to drupal 8. Therefore I created a module "myimageflow".
"myimageflow.libraries.yml" seems to be ok according to function myimageflow_library_status(), but neither I can see a message from "hook_library_info_alter()" nor does does the "hook_requirements()" function seems to be successfull:

Here the "myimageflow.libraries.yml" file:

```
imageflow:
  remote: https://finnrudolph.com/
  license:
    name: Creative Commons BY-NC 3.0
    url: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0/deed.en
    gpl-compatible: true
  version: 1.x
  js:
    imageflow.packed.js: { minified: true }

imageflow_integration:
 js:
   js/imageflow.load.js: {}
```

I called the function myimageflow_library_status() with

```
dpm(myimageflow_library_status());
```

This function

```
function myimageflow_library_status(){
  $library_discovered = \Drupal::service('library.discovery')->getLibrariesByExtension('myimageflow');
  return $library_discovered;
}
```

shows me this:

```
Array
(
[imageflow] => Array
    (
        [remote] => https://finnrudolph.com/
        [license] => Array
            (
                [name] => Creative Commons BY-NC 3.0
                [url] => https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0/deed.en
                [gpl-compatible] => 1
            )

        [version] => 1.x
        [js] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [minified] => 1
                        [group] => -100
                        [type] => file
                        [data] => modules/custom/myimageflow/imageflow.packed.js
                        [version] => 1.x
                    )

            )

        [dependencies] => Array
            (
            )

        [css] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[imageflow_integration] => Array
    (
        [js] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [group] => -100
                        [type] => file
                        [data] => modules/custom/myimageflow/js/imageflow.load.js
                        [version] => -1
                        [minified] => 
                    )

            )

        [dependencies] => Array
            (
            )

        [css] => Array
            (
            )

        [license] => Array
            (
                [name] => GNU-GPL-2.0-or-later
                [url] => https://www.drupal.org/licensing/faq
                [gpl-compatible] => 1
            )

    )
)
```

So I assume that drupal would recognize the library "imageflow" in "modules/custom/myimageflow/imageflow/..." which I installed with chmod 777 for testing purposes exactly there.

But the function hook_library_info_alter() gives me nothing:

```
/**
* Implements hook_library_info_alter().
*/
function myimageflow_library_info_alter(&$libraries, $extension) {
  // Optionally use the Libraries module to determine our library paths.
  if ($extension == 'myimageflow' && \Drupal::moduleHandler()
  ->moduleExists('libraries')
  ){
    dpm($libraries,"Libraries");
  }
}
```

And in my file "myimageflow.install" the function hook_requirements() is also not successfull:

```
/**
* Implements hook_requirements.
*/
function myimageflow_requirements($phase) {
  $requirements = array();
  if ($phase == 'runtime') {
  $library = libraries_detect('imageflow');
// Library is cached, so we must look at path to see if something got lost.
$path = $library['library path'];
if (!$path) {
  $url = Url::fromUri('https://finnrudolph.de/produkte/imageflow/download', array('attributes' => array('target' => '_blank')));
  $external_link = \Drupal::l(t('ImageFlow'), $url);
  $requirements['imageflow'] = array(
    'title' => t('Imageflow library'),
    'severity' => REQUIREMENT_ERROR,
    'value' => t('Library required for Imageflow'),
    'description' => t('You need to install the Imageflow library. The js '
        . 'file should be readable at sites/*/libraries/imageflow/imageflow.js. '
        . 'You can find the library at @url.', array('@url'=> $external_link)),
  );
}
else {
  $options = $library['version arguments'];
  $version = libraries_get_version($library, $options);
  $requirements['imageflow'] = array(
    'value' => $version,
    'severity' => REQUIREMENT_OK,
  );
}
$requirements['imageflow']['title'] = t('Imageflow library');
}
return $requirements;
}
```

Comment: `libraries_detect` does this function still exist in Drupal 8? I can't find it.

Comment: function libraries_detect(): libraries.module line 546

Comment: I can’t find it in the docs for 8.x.

Comment: This works actually in flexslider ("flexslider.install" line 31) and in masonry("masonsry.install" line 23). So this works, although with deprecated code!